# Morphisms from the empty diagram

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, abstract-nonsense

Let $X$ be an object in a category, and let $D$ be the empty diagram in the same category (containing no objects, and therefore no morphisms).

What should $\text{Hom}(D,X)$ be?

The only reasonable answers seem to me to be either one point or the empty set. A few sources I've looked at seem to imply that should be one point. Is this merely a convention, or is there a good natural reason to adopt this answer over the other?

Comment: What do you mean in general by a morphism between an object and a diagram, in either direction?

Comment: The obvious definition seems to be a collection of morphisms, one $X \rightarrow Y$ for each object $Y$ of $D$, commuting with all of the arrows in the diagram.

Comment: That's generally known as a [cone](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cone#cones_over_a_diagram) under or over the diagram, and is equivalent to a natural transformation to/from a constant diagram as in Maxime's answer.  Note that the definition directly yields the conclusion that there is exactly one cone over or under the empty diagram with any given vertex.

Comment: Any time you ask for a collection of data, one datum for each $Y \in \emptyset$ [such that ...], you fill find that there is a unique such collection.

Comment: [As of this comment, there are currently two votes to close this question. This question should not be closed. It is a perfectly reasonable question that arises when one tries to understand the finer points of category theory.]

Answer (score 5):

$\emptyset$ is the initial category therefore $Fun(\emptyset, C)$ is the terminal category for any $C$.

So, if by "morphism to/from an object $X$ from/to the empty diagram $D$", you mean from/to the constant diagram at $X$, then both of these are indeed just a point. This is not a mere convention, but a calculation, in the same way that $\hom(\emptyset, X)$ only has one element for any set $X$.

If you mean something else, then you should make that more precise.

Comment: I would maybe not say "is reduced to a point...", but rather "has only one element...". It's not being 'reduced' from anything! :-)

Comment: @DavidRoberts : huh I thought it was standard terminology ! My bad, maybe it's only so in french :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit (I'm thinking from a pedagogical angle, in particular, here)